# Constant pointer array or pointer to an array ? What is faster in C?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, pointer-arithmetic

Hello I'm in an intermediary C class right now and this thought just came to my mind:

```
int multi[3][4]; // const multidimensional array

int* ptr = *multi; // ptr is a pointer variable that hold the address of multi const array
```

So, what is faster/smaller/optimized for access a multidimensional array position?

This:

```
multi[3][1]; // index the value position
```

or

```
*(*(multi+2)+1); // pointer to the position on the array
```

or (UPDATED)

```
ptr += 9; // pointer arithmetic using auxiliary pointer
```

Since "multi" is an const array the compiler should "know" already the localization of the element position, in case of using an variable pointer pointing to that array that could take more processing time, on the other hand could be faster when searching for the item that I want to display. What is the faster/smaller/optimized approach?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You should be caring more about the readability of the code. Most people don't realize that you can't answer "nano" performance comparisons about C. You can answer such questions, but you have to specify an implementation(or a set of implementations).

Comment: Make it readable.  Even *if* there were performance gains to be had -- and I doubt there are -- go with the readable version.  "Premature optimization is the root of all evil."  -Knuth

Comment: C is already a tough language to work with. Why would you want to make it harder?

Comment: Well someone should say that to my professor. His words: 1.*(ptr+1) is cheating; 2. you should never user arr[row][col]; etc

Comment: @Maris Melo: *sigh*. This is yet another argument against using C as a teaching language; the amount of folklore, misinformation, and plain bad practice that has been institutionalized is staggering. The reason so many students have problems with C is because it's usually taught badly.  Tell your professor to code up and profile the different versions; he may be amazed at the results.

Comment: Because I just can't let this go, I womped up a small program that walks through a 2D array, once by indexing and then by pointer arithmetic, and profiled it.  On my system, using subscripts is *consistently* faster than using pointer arithmetic, by upwards of 20%.  Too many people like your professor "know" that tricky code is "faster" than the straightforward version, and more often than not they turn out to be **wrong**.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They're all compiled in the same way, `*(pointer_to_first_element + x + y)`.

Comment: See my answer below.  Using regular subscript operators resulted in the fewest instructions (for that code and compiler settings).

Comment: @john: I guess 5 of my 7 upvotes should be for you.. ;) I did a similar work for single-dimensional arrays and the asm generated was the same, so I supposed the asm would be the same for bi-dimensional array too.

Answer (score 6):

Firstly

```
int multi[3][4];
```

is not a `const` array. There is nothing `const` in this declaration.

Secondly,

```
int* ptr = *multi;
```

will make `ptr` point to the element `multi[0][0]`. Numerically it is the same as the address of `multi[0]` and the address of the entire `multi`, but the types are different.

Thirdly,

```
multi[3][1];
```

is by definition the same as

```
*(*(multi + 3) + 1);
```

so there can be no justified difference in performance. How it is connected to what was said above is not clear.

Fourthly,

```
*ptr + 9;
```

has no "pointer arithmetic" in it whatsoever. It is equivalent to

```
multi[0][0] + 9;
```

which is an ordinary integral addition. Again, how it is connected to what was said above is not clear.

Finally, your question is titled as "Constant pointer array or pointer to an array", while in the actual text of the question I see neither.

Comment: Regarding *ptr + 9, it is worth mentioning it contains no pointer arithmetic because unary * operator has higher priority than binary +. Had the code been *ptr++ it would have contained pointer arithmetic. ++ has equal priority as *, but in this case, the operators are evaluated right-to-left. These rules are by no means simple to keep track of, and this is why you shouldn't rely on operator precedence but use parenthesis, whenever mixing multiple operators on one line.

Comment: @Lundin: I don't know why you overcomplicate the "priority" issue so much. In C/C++ unary operators always have higher priority than binary operators, and postfix operators always have higher priority thna prefix ones. What's the point of assigning *equal* priority for unary `*` and postfix `++`?

Comment: It is the standard which overcomplicates it. Actually I wasn't correct, postfix++ has higher priority than *, I confused the postfix priority with the prefix one. My point is, these operator presedence rules are a pain to keep track of, so use parenthesis! Don't rely on them nor assume that programmers know them or remember them.

Comment: @Lundin: The standard does not have any operator precedence rules. The standard has the grammar that defines the grouping of operators and operands. And in this specific case it is very simple, again: unary operators have higher priority than binary operators, and postfix operators have higher priority than prefix ones.

Comment: @Andrey You are correct about the grouping, although they are part of the operator precedence rules. See ISO 9899:1999 6.5 $3 "The grouping of operators and operands is indicated by the syntax. 74)", Note 74: "The syntax specifies the precedence of operators in the evaluation of an expression, which is the same as the order of the major subclauses of this subclause, highest precedence first."

Comment: @Lundin: But that's what I'm talking about. The "syntax" of the language is its grammar. The grammar defines grouping and precedence. The precedence is generally non-linear, meaning that generally it is impossible to arrange all operators in a sequence according to their precedence. Which is why you won't find any "operator precedence tables" in the standard.

Comment: @Andrey Nope it doesn't have any *tables* but it does have presedence *rules* :)  Those tables reflect the standard grouping however, unless the author of them screwed up somehow.

Comment: @Lundin: The point I'm making is that the standard does not have any *explicit* precedence rules. The rules are implicit. And, again, it is impossible to express these rules by a linear table, because C/C++ precedence is non-linear. An immediate example would be `?:` operator, which does not have a specific place in any linear sequence of precedences. Any "table" that includes `?:` is always "screwed up" in that regard.

Comment: @Andrey "Note 74" that I cited states explicitly (though well-hidden) that the order is the same as the chapters describing them appear in the standard. First primary expressions, then postfix, then unary (prefix) and so on.

Comment: @Lundin: The very same note goes further to explain that this linear ordering is generally invalid, since it contains a number of *exceptions*. They are explicitly listed in that note. You conveniently omitted that part of the note. The list of exception includes `?:` operator I mentioned above. BTW, this is why it was made a *note*, since notes are *non-normative*. I.e. whatever notes say generally does not matter and can easily be only an approximate version of the truth (as we observe in this case). What matters is 6.5/3: "The grouping of operators and operands is indicated by the syntax".

Comment: @Lundin: Basically, this note, when taken in its entirety, says exactly what I was saying above all the time, word to word. What are you trying to prove by quiting that note to me is not immediately clear.

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't matter how fast your code is if it gets tossed because nobody else can understand and maintain it; also, tricky code can sometimes prevent your compiler from making a better optimization.

For example:

```
int main(void)
{
  int arr[3][4] = {{0,1,2,3},{4,5,6,7},{8,9,10,11}};
  int *p = *arr; // == arr[0] == &arr[0][0]

  int x;

  x = arr[2][3];         // Straightforward array access
  x = *(*(arr+2)+3);     // Ugly pointer arithmetic
  x = *(ptr + 11);       // Slightly less ugly pointer arithmetic

  return 0;
}
```

I ran the above through `gcc -c -g -Wa,-a,-ad > foo.lst` to get the generated assembly and source code interleaved.

Here's the translation for `x = arr[2][3];`:

```
movl      -16(%ebp), %eax     
movl      %eax, -8(%ebp)
```

Here's the translation for `x = *(*(arr+2)+3);`:

```
leal      -60(%ebp), %eax
addl      $44, %eax
movl      (%eax), %eax
movl      %eax, -8(%ebp)
```

And finally, the translation for `x = *(ptr + 11);`:

```
movl      -12(%ebp), %eax
addl      $44, %eax
movl      (%eax), %eax
movl      %eax, -8(%ebp)
```

**Don't try to outsmart your compiler**.  This isn't the 1970s anymore.  gcc knows how to do array accesses efficiently without you having to tell it.

You shouldn't even be *thinking* about performance at this level **unless** you've tuned your algorithm and data structures, used the highest optimization settings on your compiler (FWIW, `-O1` generates the same code for all three versions), and you're *still* failing to meet a hard performance requirement (in which case, the right answer is usually to buy faster hardware).  And you shouldn't change *anything* without first running your code through a profiler to find the real bottlenecks.  *Measure*, don't guess.

**EDIT**

Naturally, when the literals `2` and `3` are replaced by variables, the situation changes.  In that case, the `*(ptr + offset);` comes out looking the best.  But not by much.  And I'll still argue that clarity matters more at this level.

Answer (score 2):

`a[i]` **means** `*(a+i)`, in fact you can also write `i[a]` and your compiler will accept it.

`*(ptr+i)` anyway could be slightly faster than `ptr[j][k]` in theory, since you're doing a single addition (while `ptr[j][k]` could require 2).

Comment: `a[i]` means `*(a+i)` not `(a+i)`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure where the const arrays came from, but for the discussion, lets assume there were some in the original post.

As the original poster didn't explicitly mention PC programming, const arrays and regular arrays are not necessarily compiled in the same way.

In embedded systems, const arrays *may* be slower than non-const ones, if the const arrays are allocated in true non-volatile memory, ie an embedded application with real ROM. The slowness is related to access times of the ROM, and highly hardware-specific.

---

Regarding pointer arithmetic, that is the only way to access arrays. The array syntax in the C language is what the compiler people call "syntactic sugar", i.e it is just there for looks. An array access like

arr[i]

is translated by the compiler to

*(arr+i)

and they are equivalent in performance and function.